# s3 select to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I am using S3 Select to read the csv file and outputting into JSON. Now I want the JSON Output from S3 Select into pandas dataframe. Is it possible to convert S3 Select JSON output to pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Not Sure if you still are looking for an answer but this worked for me:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = bucket_name

file_name = file_key

sql_stmt = """SELECT S.* FROM s3object S LIMIT 10"""


req = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Key=file_key,
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression=sql_stmt,
    InputSerialization = {'CSV': {'FileHeaderInfo': 'USE'}},
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
)

records = []
for event in req['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records.append(event['Records']['Payload'])
    elif 'Stats' in event:
        stats = event['Stats']['Details']


file_str = ''.join(r.decode('utf-8') for r in records)

select_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file_str))
print(len(select_df))
df = pd.DataFrame(select_df)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to look at it is knowing its type('event' type), it will be dict.
so converting dict to pandas is easy:

```
dict_ = {'key 1': 'value 1', 'key 2': 'value 2', 'key 3': 'value 3'}
pd.DataFrame([dict_])
```